# How can I apply a check to run a cron file(.php file) from only my servers scheduled cron command

Tags: php, joomla, ip, server

Actually I want to apply a check to run my cron only from my server, as it is a cron file and run through command it doesn't give any IP address. So i can't apply ip check here.

I just applied check right now that if I get blank IP, means file run through command(scheduled cron) at server. I know it is not safe.

Please give me your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A common method can be found in the Joomla `/cli` files, which check for the existence of the key `REQUEST_METHOD` in the global `$_SERVER`.

```
// Make sure we're being called from the command line, not a web interface
if (array_key_exists('REQUEST_METHOD', $_SERVER)) die();
```